# Which linux C/C++ SOAP library? Need very lightweight recommendations

Tags: c++, linux, soap, arm

I need to do just *one* SOAP over HTTP request in an application. No other transports than HTTP, i'll just to the request and crunch the response. Due to it being just one request, i don't really need something that has a c++ code generator from WSDL, just some API to build the request with.
This will be on a cpu and memory constrained system (arm), also generally crippled in the support libraries department.
I can do plain C or C++, i have some kind of (also crippled) STL, but not much else and i'd rather not add too many megabytes of libraries.
I have libxml2 (not sure if it has any connection, but i'm a SOAP noob) on my target platform.
Needs to compile on gcc/linux, of course. I can handle any x86->arm transition oddities.
gSOAP is out of the question because of licensing and hugeness.
Some googling led me to http://simplesoap.sourceforge.net/ but i'd like to hear if there are any alternatives before i dive in.
So, any other sugesstions from fellow SO members? Thank you.

---

simpleSOAP doesn't compile with a modern gcc (example: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]). I can probably fix that but not for one request.
So... manual it is...

Comment: Checked cpp-netlib ? http://cpp-netlib.github.com/

Comment: @ArunMu: good link, I do not know this one, thanks !

Comment: @Torp: Good question (+1) ! simple soap seems OK. I've made an answer to suggest an alternative

Comment: @ArunMu upvoted because i didn't know of that library either, but it's only http - i have curl for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it is that simple, you can use a low level HTTP lib like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and code your request by hand or using an xml lib.

I do not know simplesoap. I've just browsed the site, it seems adequate ^^

I agree with you on gSoap :)

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Half-decade late to see this one, but I wanted to mention another project.

[csoap](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/), it's written in C and uses libxml.
I'm note sure about all it's features, but it should definitly be an improvment over full manual.

Comment: csoap is LGPL, mentioning this because OP said gsoap (GPLv2) was too restrictive. so I'm assuming they don't want to statically link csoap either.

Comment: I think what you are saying is true, however I personally don't interpret the LGPL in nearly as permissible manner as you. Can you provide an example of a Microsoft program that is *not* open source and statically links to LGPL code?

Comment: @WilburWhateley  libgit2.github.com correcting myself it would be slightly less restrictive, since it's GPL with static exception.   Looks like you pretty much have to link dynamically for an LGPL library... which obviously one should do for a solid library, and not be a stooge and use a POS simply because it's permissibly licensed